# What's the purpose of each directory?

Tags: 7

What's the purpose of the directories used from Drupal?

Comment: For Drupal 8, check: [What are all the directories for in the new Drupal 8 structure?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/84811/1908)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I haven't seen one, so let's start a list right here. In Drupal 5, 6 and 7 the structure looks like this:

- includes - include files with php functions and classes that make up the Drupal API
- misc - miscellaneous assets like javascript files and images
- modules - Drupal core modules (not meant for contrib and custom modules)
- profiles - installation profiles
- scripts - shell scripts for developers and administrators
- sites - all files that are added by a developer to create a site

  - sites/all/libraries - 3rd party libraries, eg. a wysiwyg editor
  - sites/all/modules - contributed and custom modules
  - sites/all/themes - contributed and custom (sub)themes
  - sites/default - contains the default settings.php
  - sites/default/files - the default directory for user-uploaded files
  - sites/example.com/modules - the site-specific modules directory in a multisite structure
  - sites/example.com/themes - the site-specific themes directory in a multisite structure
  - sites/example.com/files - the site-specific directory for user-uploaded files in a multisite structure
- themes - Drupal core themes

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is good. This is just my two cents to expand other answers, as a site developer on Drupal 7. It is easier to navigate when upgrading many custom modules, few features, and parent/custom sub-themes.

- sites/all

  - /modules

    - /contrib
    - /custom
    - /features
  - /libraries
  - /themes
- sites/example.com

  - same as sites/all/* with site-instance specific needs when appropriate

Comment: I want exactly the same thing on Drupal 7 that you have mentioned in your answer but i am wondering how can i install new module in `sites/all/modules/custom` directory. Please help on this.

Comment: I really havent tried placing modules to custom directory with drupal ui (ftp). I just ftp/ssh them there directly or assign it in makefile. As a sidenote installation and making module available are different thing as latter implies system modifications.