# What are all the directories for?

Tags: 8

Drupal 8 re-arranged all the directories and locations of modules/themes etc. Where do things go now?

Comment: For Drupal 5, 6, 7, check http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/11410.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

- **/core** contains all the files provided by core that doesn't have an explicit reason to be in the / directory.
- **/libraries** contains third-party libraries. It's not used by Drupal core, but it's commonly found in many sites.
- **/modules** is the directory into which all custom and contributed modules go.
  This directory contains the **contrib** and **custom** sub-directories, which can be used to make easier to keep track of the modules.
- **/profiles** contains contributed and custom profiles.
- **/themes** contains contributed and custom (sub)themes.
- **/sites** is the directory used for running Drupal multi-site setups and it's used in the same way as in Drupal 7. Modules and themes in **/sites/all/modules** and **/sites/all/themes** will override the ones in the base **modules** and **themes** directories. Modules in **/sites/SITENAME/modules** and **/sites/SITENAME/themes** will override others for the given site.
- **/vendor** is the directory where Composer dependencies go, for example Symfony and Twig.

Details on the /core directory, primarily useful to know for new core hackers:

- **/core/assets** - Various external libraries used by Core. jQuery, underscore, modernizer etc.
- **/core/misc** - Frontend code that Drupal Core depends on.
- **/core/includes** - Functionality that is to low level to be modular. Such as the module system itself.
- **/core/lib** - Drupal Core classes.
- **/core/modules** - Drupal Core modules.
- **/core/profiles** - Drupal Core installation profiles. Minimal, Standard, Testing and Testing multilingual installation profiles by default.
- **/core/scripts** - Various CLI scripts, mostly used by developers.
- **/core/tests** - Drupal Core tests.
- **/core/themes** - Drupal Core themes.

Comment: What about the folder for (uploaded) files?

Comment: Excellent question, there's also the new configuration files to take into account. I'll add those as well.

Comment: @unor Fixed now. :)

Comment: Have an upvote for the /libraries tip. Honestly that should be a bare directory with the core install so it is clear thats where things go... it wasn't clear to me at first.