# File directories question

Tags: theming, 8, files

I've started learning Drupal 8 and I have question about file directories.

Previously on D7 I've set directories like this:

files - /sites/all/files

modules - /sites/all/modules

themes - /sites/all/themes

Usually I don't make multisites, so can I set directories like this for D8?

files - /files

modules - /modules

themes - /themes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drupal 8, `/modules` and `/themes` are already in the root for you. Within them, you can also do `/contrib` and `/custom` for further organization.

I have never put files in the root, but I suppose *you could* as long as you ignore it with git.

See this answer for more detail: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/84851/57