# webform libraries dir location

Tags: 8, webforms

The webform status report states several libraries are needed.
After downloading the zip file.. and extracting it.  Where does '/libraries/' directory belong? ie: /modules/webform/libraries  Or ???

Answer (score 5):

It's literally /libraries in your web root, not in a subfolder. This is from the *Base-Level Directories* section of the [Directory Structure](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/understanding-drupal/directory-structure) docs (which began life [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84811/what-are-all-the-directories-for-in-the-new-drupal-8-structure)):

> **/libraries** - All third party external libraries leveraged by Drupal, such as a WYSIWYG editor. This folder is not included by core, but used with many contributed modules.

Answer (score 2):

It's written inside `webform.libraries.yml` where these 3rd party libraries are supposed to be located.

Their paths all start with `/libraries/...` (`/` means Drupal web root) whereas Webform's own libraries paths all start with just `js/...` (which means relative to the `webform.libraries.yml` file).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drush webform-libraries-download`.