# migrating from localhost to server - What to do with the folder sites/localhost.mysitename?

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

I am trying to migrate my site from acquia dev desktop (local host server) to bluehost.
In my site on my computer I have inside the "sites" folder, 3 folders:

- all
- default
- **localhost.mysitename**

Inside **localhost.mysitename** I have the "**files**" folder, and inside that I have the following folders: adaptive theme, banner, color, ctools, custom_search, custom_search, feeds, pictures, styles, styles. in addition I have the ".htaccess" file and many pictures and logos of the site.

Should I change the folder name of "localhost.mysitename" to only "mysitename"? 
Should I change it at all or to other name?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the acquia product you are using. And I don't know bluehost - but it seems to be a "usual webhoster". I assume at bluehost is an ordinary LAMP stack running without any drupal-specific modifications.

*update 2 after comments of EB84:*

It turns out you are not using multi-sites. Seems to me as you made your setup more difficult than it needs to be:

Just replace the default folder with your localhost.mysitename folder. By doing so you revert your folder-structure back to a simple single-site setup.

Keep in mind, that you need to adopt your settings.php to the preferences of your bluehost webspace (database parameters, etc.). Your settings.php will look different on the server than on your local machine - all other files and directories may be the same.

*update 1 after comment of EB84:*

Since you are using a multi-site setup the configuration in `sites/sites.php` will control which site will be used for what domain names in HTTP requests.

Please read following documents:

- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!example.sites.php/7
- https://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site

You will read that the directory names are arbitrary - as long as you map the domain name of the HTTP requests to it (via the configuration in sites.php).

Anyhow it might be good to remove the term "localhost" from your directory name - not for the whole thing to run technically, but to not confuse yourself some when in future.

Comment: Hello. I updated my question. you think I should transfer all content from the folder "localhost.mysitename" to the "default" folder?

Comment: Is there anything in the default folder? Like custom modules, themes etc.?

Comment: No. I have there "default.settings.php", and folder with only two pictures I put there. Oh, on the bluehost, there is there a "setting.php" file. Inside the "localhost.mysite" folder I have a "settings.php" file and a folder called "files". Inside this "files" folder I have many folders of the adaptive theme, banner, color, ctools, custom_search, custom_search, feeds, pictures, styles, styles. in addition I have the ".htaccess" file and many pictures and logos of the site.. I think this "localhost.mysitename/files" is important directories. What should I do?

Comment: Okay. I see. In this case the whole multi-site setup is too much for you. Just replace the default folder with your localhost.mysitename folder and you are good to go. I'll update my answer again...

Comment: For better understanding of what directories you see in your drupal folder: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11410/is-there-anywhere-a-good-writeup-on-drupal-directory-structure

Comment: Thanks. After I moved everything from the "localhost.mysitename" to the "default" folder. I tried to open the site, and I got a screen like a fresh installation of drupal. then, on the database step, I got an error: Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in DatabaseConnection->__construct() (line 304 of D:\intenet project\SITES FOLDERS\mysitename\includes\database\database.inc).

Comment: Did you move the settings.php file too? If you don't do that the behaviour of drupal is to start the installation process...

Comment: But why your MySQL is refusing connections is nothing I could solve here. Check if it's running.
Maybe here is some magic of your acquia tool going on?

Comment: I did moved the settings.php. what happened? I need to move it, or not?
I change the update to "TRUE" on the setting.php file..

Comment: yes. delete the default folder and rename the localhost.mysitename folder to default --> everything should be moved.

Comment: the update flag in the settings doesn't do anything here in this case. For production sites this may be switched to FALSE.

Comment: Get your database troubles fixed - I guess this is causing this weired behaviour of drupal.

Comment: I deleted the default folder and rename the localhost.mysitename folder to default. everything work great / regulary... I will update if I will have more question on this. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I have been using acquia dev desktop for a long time now, and the folder you are speaking about is basically nothing and you can delete it.

I you compare this folder to the default folder, you will notice that they are identical in contents.

This what i usually do to all of my websites, and is working as expected !