# Why do I get duplicated files?

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

I am creating a Drupal site using Acquia Dev Desktop. I have noticed that there seems to be duplicate files located at C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\columbiablooms-dev\docroot\sites\all and C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\openoutreach-7.x-1.19\sites.

*Columbiablooms* is the name of the site I'm building. Using Acquia Dev Desktop I pushed the site up to Acquia. What is the relationship between the two file paths?

Does the C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\columbiablooms-dev folder have anything to do with multisite or is it necessary for Acquia Dev Desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\columbiablooms-dev** contains data for your Acquia site (e.g. **hooks** has scripts that can trigger upon deployment, **private** contains files that setup as private in Drupal's file system, etc.)

The **C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\columbiablooms-dev\docroot** dir is the webroot of your site; this is the dir that is the base of your domain that is uploaded to Acquia (e.g. C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\columbiablooms-dev\docroot\index.php -> http://www.example.com/index.php). See [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/11412/45675) for an explanation of all the subdirectories.

**C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\openoutreach-7.x-1.19** is a copy of OpenOutreach 1.19 you downloaded. It contains the OpenOutreach installation profile, its needed modules/themes, and the version of Drupal it's bundled with.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and for being patient with a newbie. Why is there duplication of files? I ran across a problem trying to remove mailchimp. I discovered that mailchimp was in both locations.

Comment: I presume it was downloaded as a part of some installation process. I don't know. How did you install OpenOutreach? The docroot dir should contain everything with your Drupal install.

Comment: I was pretty careful about installing the Open Outreach distribution, but there's always the possibility that I misunderstood instructions. I've learned quite a bit about Drupal over the last several weeks, but there are areas that are still unclear.

Comment: Unless you've changed something with DevDesktop, you should be fine removing that; your entire install should be contained under docroot. You can test it by temporarily removing that folder and testing that your local copy still is functional.